# BA network generator and Percolator with OpenMP and also Linear code

Tags: c++, openmp

Here I uploaded a very basic Barabasi-Albert network generator and then a percolator which conducts percolation over the network following some rules. I have used openmp to parallelize the loops.

Here 3 arrays, `maxclus`,`delmx` and `entropycalc` are shared between the parallel threads and `netmap1`,`netmap2`,`ptr` and `random` are made private to the threads. What it basically does is that, suppose you have a vector, and two arrays, then,

```
int* arrayresult = new int [N];
int* array;
#pragma omp parallel shared(arrayresult) private(array)
{
   vector<int> someVec;
   array = new int [N]
   for(int k=0;k<somenum;k++) array[k] = 0;
   #pragma omp for 
   for(int i=0;i<somenum;i++)
   {

      // do something with someVec;
      // do something with array;
      for(int j=0;j<somenum1;j++)
      #pragma omp atomic
      arrayresult[j] += someResult;
   }
   delete [] array;
}
```

Now this snippet describes the main gist of the code I am posting here. This shows a performance degradation proportional to the number of cores or threads being used. I am providing both the linear code and the parallel code.

How can I make the parallel one more efficient?

[Parallel Code with OpenMP](https://pastebin.com/i9smRx5M)

```
//compile with icpc filename.cpp -o executable -O3 -std=c++14 -qopenmp

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#include<random>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<omp.h>

//#include "openacc_curand.h"
using namespace std;

int EMPTY = 0;
int connectionNumber = 0; // it indexes the connection between different nodes of the network

// this function does the union find work for the percolation
//#pragma acc routine seq
int findroot(int ptr[],int i)
{
    if(ptr[i]<0) return i;

    return ptr[i]=findroot(ptr,ptr[i]);
}   



int main()
{
    int seed,vertices,m,run,filenum,M;



    //I am just going to set the initial value for your need
    /*
    cout<<"enter seed size: ";
    cin>>seed;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter vertice number: ";
    cin>>vertices;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"order number: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"order of Explosive Percolation: ";
    cin>>M;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter ensemble number: ";
    cin>>run;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter filenumber: ";
    cin>>filenum;
    cout<<endl;
*/
    seed = 6;
    vertices = 500000;
    m = 5;
    M = 12;
    run = 50;
    filenum = 1;

    //this sets up the connection and initializes the array;
    int con = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<seed;i++)
    {
        con = con + i;
    }

    con = con + (vertices-seed)*m;

    //int* netmap1 = new int[con+1]; //node 1 that is connected to a certain connectionNumber
    //int* netmap2 = new int[con+1]; //node 2 that is connected to a certain connectionNumber

    //for(int i=1;i<=con;i++)
    //{
    //  netmap1[i] = 0;
    //  netmap2[i] = 0;
    //}

    connectionNumber = con;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int A,B,C;
    A = vertices;
    B = run;
    C = filenum;

    //saved filename

    string filename1;
    filename1 = "maxclus_";
    string filename2;
    filename2 = "delmx_";
    string filename3;
    filename3 = "entropy_";

    filename1 = filename1+to_string(A)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(B)+"ens"+to_string(C)+".dat";
    filename2 = filename2+to_string(vertices)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(run)+"ens"+to_string(filenum)+".dat";
    filename3 = filename3+to_string(vertices)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(run)+"ens"+to_string(filenum)+".dat";

    ofstream fout1,fout2,fout3;//,fout3;

    //int* random = NULL;
    //random = new int[connectionNumber+1];

    double* maxclus = NULL;
    maxclus = new double[vertices+1];

    double* delmx = NULL;
    delmx = new double[connectionNumber+1];

    double* entropycalc = NULL;
    entropycalc = new double[connectionNumber+1];

    for(int i=0;i<=vertices;i++)
    {
        maxclus[i]=0;
        delmx[i]=0;
        entropycalc[i]=0;
    }

    //for(int i=0;i<=connectionNumber;i++)
    //{
    //  random[i] = i;
    //}

    //this is the pointer that needs to be made private for all the parallel loops
    //int* ptr = new int[vertices+1];
    //for(int i=0;i<vertices+1;i++) ptr[i]=0;

    //the main program starts here 

    int* ptr; int* netmap1; int* netmap2; int* random;
    int runcounter = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(con,runcounter,maxclus,delmx,entropycalc) private(ptr,netmap1,netmap2,random) firstprivate(connectionNumber)
    {

    ptr = new int[vertices+1];
    netmap1 = new int[connectionNumber+1];
    netmap2 = new int[connectionNumber+1];
    random = new int[connectionNumber+1];

    for(int l=0;l<=con;l++)
        {
            netmap1[l] = 0;
            netmap2[l] = 0;
            random[l] = l;
        }

        for(int l=0;l<=vertices;l++)
        ptr[l] = EMPTY;
    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(int i=1;i<=run;i++)
    {
        //#pragma omp critical
        //cout<<"run : "<<i<<endl;
        //vector<size_t> network;   

        vector<int> network;    

        /*for(int l=0;l<=con;l++)
        {
            netmap1[l] = 0;
            netmap2[l] = 0;
            random[l] = l;
        }

        for(int l=0;l<=vertices;l++)
        ptr[l] = EMPTY;*/

        connectionNumber = 0;   

        //cout<<network.capacity()<<endl;

        //seeds are connected to the network    
        for(int i=1;i<=seed;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=seed;j++)
            {
                if(j>i)
                {

                    connectionNumber=connectionNumber + 1;
                    netmap1[connectionNumber]=i; //connections are addressed
                    netmap2[connectionNumber]=j;
                    network.push_back(i); // the vector is updated for making connection
                    network.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }   

        int concheck = 0;
        int ab[m]; //this array checks if a node is chosen twice
        int countm = 0;

        for(int i = seed+1;i<=vertices; i++)
        {
            countm = 0;
            for(int k=0;k<m;k++) ab[k] = 0;

            for(int j = 1; ;j++)
            {
                concheck = 0;
                int N1=network.size() ;
                int M1=0;                   
                int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);

                for(int n=0;n<m;n++)
                {
                    if(ab[n] == network[u]) concheck = 1;
                }

                //if condition is fulfilled the connection are given to the nodes
                //the data is saved in the arrays of the connection
                if(concheck == 0 && network[u]!=i)  
                {
                    ab[countm] = network[u];
                    countm=countm+1;



                    connectionNumber=connectionNumber+1;
                    netmap1[connectionNumber] = i;
                    netmap2[connectionNumber] = network[u];

                    network.push_back(i);
                    network.push_back(network[u]);
                }

                if(countm==m) break;

            }
        }
        //the random list of connection are shuffled


        random_shuffle(&random[1],&random[con]);


        for(int rx=1;rx<=1;rx++)
        {           
            int index=0,big=0,bigtemp=0,jump=0,en1=0,en2=0;

            int nodeA=0,nodeB=0;

            int indx1=0;

            int node[2*M+1];// = {0};
            int clus[2*M+1];// = {0};


            double entropy = log(vertices);



            for(int i=0;i<=vertices;i++) ptr[i] = EMPTY;


            for(int i=1;i<=vertices;i++)
            {
                if(i!=connectionNumber)
                {


                    int algaRandomIndex = 0;

                    for(int nodeindex = 0; nodeindex<2*M; nodeindex+=2)
                    {

                        node[nodeindex] = netmap1[random[i + algaRandomIndex]];
                        node[nodeindex + 1] = netmap2[random[i + algaRandomIndex]];
                        algaRandomIndex++;
                    }

                    for(int nodeindex = 0; nodeindex<2*M; nodeindex++)
                    {
                        if(ptr[node[nodeindex]]==EMPTY) clus[nodeindex] = 1;
                        else
                        {
                            int x = findroot(ptr,node[nodeindex]);
                            clus[nodeindex] = -ptr[x];
                        }
                    }

                    int clusmul[M];
                    int clusindex1 = 0;

                    for(int clusindex = 0; clusindex<M; clusindex++)
                    {
                        clusmul[clusindex] = clus[clusindex1]*clus[clusindex1+1];
                        clusindex1 += 2;
                    }



                    bool clusmulCheck = true;
                    for(int ase = 0; ase < M; ase++)
                    {
                        bool clusmulCheck1 = true;
                        if(clusmul[ase] == 1) clusmulCheck1 = true;
                        else clusmulCheck1 = false;

                        clusmulCheck = clusmulCheck && clusmulCheck1;
                    }

                    if(clusmulCheck)
                    {
                        nodeA = node[0];
                        nodeB = node[1];

                        for(int someK = 1; someK < M; someK++)
                        {

                            int N1=connectionNumber;
                            int M1=i+M;
                            int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);



                            int temp = random[u];
                            random[u] = random[i+someK];
                            random[i+someK] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int low = clusmul[0];
                        indx1 = 1;
                        for(int as=0;as<11;as++)
                        {
                            if(clusmul[as]<low) 
                            {
                                low = clusmul[as];
                                indx1 = as+1;
                            }
                        }

                        nodeA = node[2*indx1 - 2];
                        nodeB = node[2*indx1 - 1];

                        int temp = random[i+(indx1-1)];
                        random[i+(indx1-1)] = random[i];
                        random[i] = temp;

                        for(int ase = 1; ase < M; ase++)
                        {
                            int N1=connectionNumber;
                            int M1=i+M;
                            int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);

                            int temp = random[u];
                            random[u] = random[i+ ase];
                            random[i+ ase] = temp;
                        }

                    }
                }




                if(ptr[nodeA]==EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]==EMPTY)
                {

                en1=1;
                en2=1;
                ptr[nodeA] = -2;
                ptr[nodeB] = nodeA;
                index = nodeA;
                entropy = (double)(entropy-(-2.0/vertices*log(1.0/vertices))+(-2.0/vertices*log(2.0/vertices)));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]==EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]!=EMPTY)
                {

                en1=1;
                int e = findroot(ptr,nodeB);
                en2 = -(ptr[e]);
                ptr[nodeA] = e;
                ptr[e] += -1;
                index = e;
                entropy = entropy-(-(double)1.0/vertices*log(1.0/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en2/vertices*log((double)en2/vertices))+(-( double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;


                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]!=EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]==EMPTY)
                {

                en2 = 1;
                int f = findroot(ptr,nodeA);
                en1 = -(ptr[f]);
                ptr[nodeB] = f;
                ptr[f] += -1;
                index = f;
                entropy = entropy-(-(double)1.0/(double)vertices*log(1.0/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en1/(double)vertices*log((double)en1/vertices))+(-(double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]!=EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]!=EMPTY)
                {

                    int g,h;
                    g = findroot(ptr,nodeA);
                    en1 = -(ptr[g]);
                    h = findroot(ptr,nodeB);
                    en2 = -(ptr[h]);
                    if(g!=h)
                    {
                        if(ptr[g]<ptr[h])
                        {

                            ptr[g] += ptr[h];
                            ptr[h] = g;
                            index = g;
                        }
                        else 
                        {

                            ptr[h] += ptr[g];
                            ptr[g] = h;
                            index = h;
                        }
                        entropy = entropy-(-(double)en1/(double)vertices*log((double)en1/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en2/vertices*log((double)en2/(double)vertices))+(-(double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((double)(-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                    if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        jump=big-bigtemp;
                        #pragma omp atomic 
                        maxclus[i] += big;
                        #pragma omp atomic 
                        delmx[i] += jump;
                        if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                        #pragma omp atomic
                        entropycalc[i] += entropy;
                        bigtemp = big;

                        continue;
                    }
                }   

                if(-ptr[index]>big) big = -ptr[index];

                jump = big - bigtemp;
                #pragma omp atomic  
                maxclus[i] += big;
                #pragma omp atomic
                delmx[i] += jump;

                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                #pragma omp atomic              
                entropycalc[i] += entropy;
                bigtemp = big;


            }

        }


        network.clear();

        #pragma omp atomic
        runcounter++;

        int rem = (runcounter * 100/run) % 5;

        if(rem == 0)
        cout<<"Progress: "<<(double)runcounter*100/run<<"%"<<endl;

    }

    delete [] ptr;
    delete [] netmap1;
    delete [] netmap2;
    delete [] random;


    }

    //fout1.open(filename1.c_str());
    //fout2.open(filename2.c_str());
    //fout3.open(filename3.c_str());

    connectionNumber = con;

    for(int i=1;i<=vertices;i++)
    {
        //fout1<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)maxclus[i]/vertices/run<<endl;
        //fout2<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)delmx[i]/run<<endl;
        //fout3<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)entropycalc[i]/run<<endl;
    }

    //fout1.close();
    //fout2.close();
    //fout3.close();


    //delete[] random;
    //random = NULL;
    //delete [] netmap1;
    //netmap1 = NULL;
    //delete [] netmap2;
    //netmap2 = NULL;
    //delete [] ptr;
    //ptr = NULL;

    delete[] maxclus;
    maxclus = NULL;
    delete[] delmx;
    delmx = NULL;
    delete[] entropycalc;
    entropycalc = NULL;



    return 0;

}
```

[Linear Code](https://pastebin.com/St97Z8HN)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
#include<ctime>
#include<cmath>
#include<random>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
//#include<bits/stdc++.h>
//#include "openacc_curand.h"
using namespace std;
//vector<int> network;
int EMPTY = 0;
int connectionNumber = 0; // it indexes the connection between different nodes of the network

// this function does the union find work for the percolation
//#pragma acc routine seq
int findroot(int ptr[],int i)
{
    if(ptr[i]<0) return i;

    return ptr[i]=findroot(ptr,ptr[i]);
}   

/*#pragma acc routine seq
int findroot(int ptr[],int i)
{
    //cao = 1;
    int r,s;
    r = s = i;
    while (ptr[r]>=0) 
    {
        ptr[s] = ptr[r];
        s = r;
        r = ptr[r];
    }
    return r;
}*/

int main()
{
    int seed,vertices,m,run,filenum,M;



    //I am just going to set the initial value for your need

/*  cout<<"enter seed size: ";
    cin>>seed;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter vertice number: ";
    cin>>vertices;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"order number: ";
    cin>>m;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"order of Explosive Percolation: ";
    cin>>M;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter ensemble number: ";
    cin>>run;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"enter filenumber: ";
    cin>>filenum;
    cout<<endl;
*/
    seed = 6;
    vertices = 500000;
    m = 5;
    M = 12;
    run = 50;
    filenum = 10;

    //this sets up the connection and initializes the array;
    int con = 0;

    for(int i=1;i<seed;i++)
    {
        con = con + i;
    }

    con = con + (vertices-seed)*m;

    int* netmap1 = new int[con+1]; //node 1 that is connected to a certain connectionNumber
    int* netmap2 = new int[con+1]; //node 2 that is connected to a certain connectionNumber

    for(int i=1;i<=con;i++)
    {
        netmap1[i] = 0;
        netmap2[i] = 0;
    }

    connectionNumber = con;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int A,B,C;
    A = vertices;
    B = run;
    C = filenum;

    //saved filename

    string filename1;
    filename1 = "maxclus_";
    string filename2;
    filename2 = "delmx_";
    string filename3;
    filename3 = "entropy_";

    filename1 = filename1+to_string(A)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(B)+"ens"+to_string(C)+".dat";
    filename2 = filename2+to_string(vertices)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(run)+"ens"+to_string(filenum)+".dat";
    filename3 = filename3+to_string(vertices)+"node_"+to_string(m)+"m_"+to_string(M)+"M_"+to_string(run)+"ens"+to_string(filenum)+".dat";

    ofstream fout1,fout2,fout3;//,fout3;

    int* random = NULL;
    random = new int[connectionNumber+1];

    double* maxclus = NULL;
    maxclus = new double[vertices+1];

    double* delmx = NULL;
    delmx = new double[connectionNumber+1];

    double* entropycalc = NULL;
    entropycalc = new double[connectionNumber+1];

    for(int i=0;i<=vertices;i++)
    {
        maxclus[i]=0;
        delmx[i]=0;
        entropycalc[i]=0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=connectionNumber;i++)
    {
        random[i] = i;
    }

    //this is the pointer that needs to be made private for all the parallel loops
    int* ptr = new int[vertices+1];
    for(int i=0;i<vertices+1;i++) ptr[i]=0;

    //the main program starts here 

    //#pragma acc data copy(maxclus[0:connectionNumber],delmx[0:connectionNumber],entropycalc[0:connectionNumber]), copyin(netmap1[0:connectionNumber],netmap2[0:connectionNumber])

    for(int i=1;i<=run;i++)
    {
        cout<<"run : "<<i<<endl;
        //vector<size_t> network;   
        vector<int> network;    
        connectionNumber = 0;   

        //cout<<network.capacity()<<endl;

        //seeds are connected to the network    
        for(int i=1;i<=seed;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=seed;j++)
            {
                if(j>i)
                {

                    connectionNumber=connectionNumber + 1;
                    netmap1[connectionNumber]=i; //connections are addressed
                    netmap2[connectionNumber]=j;
                    network.push_back(i); // the vector is updated for making connection
                    network.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }   

        int concheck = 0;
        int ab[m]; //this array checks if a node is chosen twice
        int countm = 0;

        for(int i = seed+1;i<=vertices; i++)
        {
            countm = 0;
            for(int k=0;k<m;k++) ab[k] = 0;

            for(int j = 1; ;j++)
            {
                concheck = 0;
                int N1=network.size() ;
                int M1=0;                   
                int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);

                for(int n=0;n<m;n++)
                {
                    if(ab[n] == network[u]) concheck = 1;
                }

                //if condition is fulfilled the connection are given to the nodes
                //the data is saved in the arrays of the connection
                if(concheck == 0 && network[u]!=i)  
                {
                    ab[countm] = network[u];
                    countm=countm+1;



                    connectionNumber=connectionNumber+1;
                    netmap1[connectionNumber] = i;
                    netmap2[connectionNumber] = network[u];

                    network.push_back(i);
                    network.push_back(network[u]);
                }

                if(countm==m) break;

            }
        }
        //the random list of connection are shuffled
        random_shuffle(&random[1],&random[connectionNumber]);

        double rand_seed = time(NULL);

        //this is where the problem lies
        //basically i want to make all the rx loops parallel in such a way that every parallel loop will have their own copy of ptr[ ] and random[ ] which they can modify themselves
        // this whole part does the 'explosive percolation' and saves the data in maxclus, delmx, entropycalc array of different runs
        //#pragma acc update device(maxclus,delmx,entropycalc,netmap1,netmap2)
        //#pragma acc data copy(maxclus[0:connectionNumber],delmx[0:connectionNumber],entropycalc[0:connectionNumber]), copyin(netmap1[0:connectionNumber],netmap2[0:connectionNumber])
        //#pragma acc parallel loop private(ptr[0:vertices+1]) firstprivate(random[0:connectionNumber])
        for(int rx=1;rx<=1;rx++)
        {           
            int index=0,big=0,bigtemp=0,jump=0,en1=0,en2=0;

            int nodeA=0,nodeB=0;

            int indx1=0;

            int node[2*M+1];// = {0};
            int clus[2*M+1];// = {0};


            double entropy = log(vertices);

            //curandState_t state;
            //curand_init(rand_seed*rx,0,0,&state);

            for(int i=0;i<=vertices;i++) ptr[i] = EMPTY;

            //#pragma acc loop seq 
            for(int i=1;i<=vertices;i++)
            {
                if(i!=connectionNumber)
                {


                    int algaRandomIndex = 0;

                    for(int nodeindex = 0; nodeindex<2*M; nodeindex+=2)
                    {

                        node[nodeindex] = netmap1[random[i + algaRandomIndex]];
                        node[nodeindex + 1] = netmap2[random[i + algaRandomIndex]];
                        algaRandomIndex++;
                    }

                    for(int nodeindex = 0; nodeindex<2*M; nodeindex++)
                    {
                        if(ptr[node[nodeindex]]==EMPTY) clus[nodeindex] = 1;
                        else
                        {
                            int x = findroot(ptr,node[nodeindex]);
                            clus[nodeindex] = -ptr[x];
                        }
                    }

                    int clusmul[M];
                    int clusindex1 = 0;

                    for(int clusindex = 0; clusindex<M; clusindex++)
                    {
                        clusmul[clusindex] = clus[clusindex1]*clus[clusindex1+1];
                        clusindex1 += 2;
                    }



                    bool clusmulCheck = true;
                    for(int ase = 0; ase < M; ase++)
                    {
                        bool clusmulCheck1 = true;
                        if(clusmul[ase] == 1) clusmulCheck1 = true;
                        else clusmulCheck1 = false;

                        clusmulCheck = clusmulCheck && clusmulCheck1;
                    }

                    if(clusmulCheck)
                    {
                        nodeA = node[0];
                        nodeB = node[1];

                        for(int someK = 1; someK < M; someK++)
                        {

                            int N1=connectionNumber;
                            int M1=i+M;
                            int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);



                            int temp = random[u];
                            random[u] = random[i+someK];
                            random[i+someK] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int low = clusmul[0];
                        indx1 = 1;
                        for(int as=0;as<11;as++)
                        {
                            if(clusmul[as]<low) 
                            {
                                low = clusmul[as];
                                indx1 = as+1;
                            }
                        }

                        nodeA = node[2*indx1 - 2];
                        nodeB = node[2*indx1 - 1];

                        int temp = random[i+(indx1-1)];
                        random[i+(indx1-1)] = random[i];
                        random[i] = temp;

                        for(int ase = 1; ase < M; ase++)
                        {
                            int N1=connectionNumber;
                            int M1=i+M;
                            int u = M1 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(N1-M1+1) + 1);

                            int temp = random[u];
                            random[u] = random[i+ ase];
                            random[i+ ase] = temp;
                        }

                    }
                }




                if(ptr[nodeA]==EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]==EMPTY)
                {

                en1=1;
                en2=1;
                ptr[nodeA] = -2;
                ptr[nodeB] = nodeA;
                index = nodeA;
                entropy = (double)(entropy-(-2.0/vertices*log(1.0/vertices))+(-2.0/vertices*log(2.0/vertices)));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]==EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]!=EMPTY)
                {

                en1=1;
                int e = findroot(ptr,nodeB);
                en2 = -(ptr[e]);
                ptr[nodeA] = e;
                ptr[e] += -1;
                index = e;
                entropy = entropy-(-(double)1.0/vertices*log(1.0/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en2/vertices*log((double)en2/vertices))+(-( double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;


                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]!=EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]==EMPTY)
                {

                en2 = 1;
                int f = findroot(ptr,nodeA);
                en1 = -(ptr[f]);
                ptr[nodeB] = f;
                ptr[f] += -1;
                index = f;
                entropy = entropy-(-(double)1.0/(double)vertices*log(1.0/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en1/(double)vertices*log((double)en1/vertices))+(-(double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                }
                else if(ptr[nodeA]!=EMPTY && ptr[nodeB]!=EMPTY)
                {

                    int g,h;
                    g = findroot(ptr,nodeA);
                    en1 = -(ptr[g]);
                    h = findroot(ptr,nodeB);
                    en2 = -(ptr[h]);
                    if(g!=h)
                    {
                        if(ptr[g]<ptr[h])
                        {

                            ptr[g] += ptr[h];
                            ptr[h] = g;
                            index = g;
                        }
                        else 
                        {

                            ptr[h] += ptr[g];
                            ptr[g] = h;
                            index = h;
                        }
                        entropy = entropy-(-(double)en1/(double)vertices*log((double)en1/(double)vertices))-(-(double)en2/vertices*log((double)en2/(double)vertices))+(-(double)(-ptr[index])/vertices*log((double)(-ptr[index])/(double)vertices));
                    if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        jump=big-bigtemp;
                        //#pragma acc atomic 
                        maxclus[i] += big;
                        //#pragma acc atomic 
                        delmx[i] += jump;
                        if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                        //#pragma acc atomic 
                        entropycalc[i] += entropy;
                        bigtemp = big;

                        continue;
                    }
                }   

                if(-ptr[index]>big) big = -ptr[index];

                jump = big - bigtemp;
                //#pragma acc atomic  
                maxclus[i] += big;
                //#pragma acc atomic 
                delmx[i] += jump;
                //#pragma acc atomic 
                if(entropy<0) entropy = 0;
                entropycalc[i] += entropy;
                bigtemp = big;


            }

        }

        //vector<size_t>().swap(network);
        //vector<int>().swap(network);
        //network.clear();
        //network.erase(network.begin(),network.end());
        //cout<<network.capacity()<<endl;
        network.shrink_to_fit();
        //cout<<network.capacity()<<endl;

            /*for(int i=0;i<connectionNumber;i++)
            {

                cout<<"maxclus: "<<maxclus[i]<<'\t'<<"delmx: "<<delmx[i]<<'\t'<<"entropy: "<<entropycalc[i]<<'\t'<<endl;

            }*/
    }

    //fout1.open(filename1.c_str());
    //fout2.open(filename2.c_str());
    //fout3.open(filename3.c_str());

    connectionNumber = con;

    for(int i=1;i<=vertices;i++)
    {
        //fout1<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)maxclus[i]/vertices/run<<endl;
        //fout2<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)delmx[i]/run<<endl;
        //fout3<<(double)i/vertices<<'\t'<<(double)entropycalc[i]/run<<endl;
    }

    //fout1.close();
    //fout2.close();
    //fout3.close();


    delete[] random;
    random = NULL;
    delete[] maxclus;
    maxclus = NULL;
    delete[] delmx;
    delmx = NULL;
    delete[] entropycalc;
    entropycalc = NULL;

    delete [] netmap1;
    netmap1 = NULL;
    delete [] netmap2;
    netmap2 = NULL;

    delete [] ptr;
    ptr = NULL;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: With a nearly 500 lines long `main()` function this code is hard to reason about. Maybe split it into multiple function? I've been staring at it for like 15 minutes, and still can't get a gist of what is actually being done. Doing so might even help the optimizer, as it then has more knowledge about the lifetime and scope of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't examined the code in great detail yet, but the first point that nearly jumped out was the use of `rand()` inside the parallelized loop.

Each call to `rand()` not only retrieves data, but also modifies a seed that's normally shared between all threads, so access to that seed is serialized. In other words, the calls to `rand` won't run in parallel. My immediate advice would be to switch to the new random number generation classes that were added in C++11. They're kind of clumsy to use initially, *but* since each generator is an object, it's trivial to have a private instance for each thread, so they can all run in parallel.

Comment: That really helped to get a performance boost. But is there any other ways to make it more efficient, like I am using `maxclus`,`delmx` and `entropycalc` as the shared arrays and `ptr` , `random`, `netmap1`, `netmap2` and a vector `network` as private, is that making any performance degradation?